# Iterating over dictionary using __getitem__ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I've implemented a python class to generate data as follows:

```
class Array:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.arr[key]

a = Array()
for i in a:
    print(i, end = " ")
```

It runs as expected and I get following

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

However, I want to do the same thing for dictionary. Why am I not able to iterate over dictionary like this?

```
class Dictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3}

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.dictionary[key]
d = Dictionary()
for key in d:
    print(key, d[key], end=" ")
```

I expect following output

```
a 1 b 2 c 3
```

But when I run above code, I get following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-33-4547779db7ec>", line 8, in <module>
    for key in d:

  File "<ipython-input-33-4547779db7ec>", line 6, in __getitem__
    return self.dictionary[key]

KeyError: 0
```

We can iterate over normal dictionary like this : `for key in d`. This iterates over all the keys, is it not possible to iterate like this using `__getitem__()`?

Comment: you need to implement an iterator pattern instead

Comment: @NikosM. I'm sorry I do not know what that means. Does it relate to some change in `__getitem()__`?

Comment: see https://treyhunner.com/2018/06/how-to-make-an-iterator-in-python/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `for` loop works with iterators, objects you can pass to `next`. An object is an iterator if it has a `__next__` method.

Neither of your classes does, so Python will first pass your object to `iter` to *get* an iterator. The first thing `iter` tries to do is call the object's `__iter__` method.

Neither of your classes defines `__iter__`, either, so `iter` next checks if its object defines `__getitem__`. Both of your classes do, so `iter` returns an object of type `iterator`, whose `__next__` method can be imagined to be something like

```
def __next__(self):
    try:
        rv = self.thing.__getitem__(self.i)
    except IndexError:
        raise StopIteration
    self.i += 1
    return rv
```

(The iterator holds a reference to the thing which defined `__getitem__`, as well as the value of `i` to track state between calls to `__next__`. `i` is presumed to be initialized to 0.)

For `Array`, this works, because it has integer indices. For `Dictionary`, though, `0` is not a key, and instead of raising an `IndexError`, you get a `KeyError` with the `__next__` method does *not* catch.

(This is alluded to in the [documentation for `__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

> Note for loops expect that an IndexError will be raised for illegal indexes to allow proper detection of the end of the sequence.

)

To make your `Dictionary` class iterable, define `__iter__`

```
class Dictionary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3}

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.dictionary[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.dictionary)
```

`dict.__iter__` returns a value of type `dict_keyiterator`, which is the thing that yields the `dict`'s keys, which you can use with `Dictionary.__getitem__`.

Comment: Can you comment on whether or not the title of my question is appropriate or not? If this is not relevant to what I'm asking I'd like to change it. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's relevant. The issue is that without any information about what the possible keys might *be*, the assumption is that the keys are the natural numbers (0, 1, 2, etc), which works for lists but not mapping types.

Comment: And while the valid arguments to `__getitem__` could be retrieved from a `dict` (for example, call the `keys` method), there's no way to do so for an arbitrary class that defines `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 8):

Adding the following method to your `Dictionary` class is sufficient to get it to work:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.dictionary)
```

Important note: When creating custom classes that are sequences or mappings, you should implement all of the relevant methods. Otherwise, your code (e.g., `x in y`, `for x in y` etc) will either be inefficient or broken as you saw in the case of your `Dictionary` class.

See for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?emulating-container-types#emulating-container-types.

Comment: Makes sense. Changed the snippet.